# I am getting error while creating simple maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, java-ee-6

I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository)
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Admin\.m2
```

[image]

Comment: Probably proxy/firewall issue.

Comment: Replace the version `RELEASE` with a literal version....